# I'm using a (session) variable to echo an employee name when they are logged into a particular module

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class='module_header'>Welcome <?php echo $data['employee'] = login::$name; ?></div>
```

Additionally, I have a select box that has various employee's names, when they select a different user name in the select box I want the page to refresh and display sql data according to the employee selected. I figure i have to do this through jquery... Looking for some direction on this.

my sql query is returning the query i'd expect for the current person logged in:

```
<?php echo lookup_gen::query_results_table("select patient_code,invoiceno,ship_date,udef1,udef2,created_at,printed, b.employee from dbo.pml_delivery_ticket_q a
left outer join  event.dbo.emp b on a.created_by=b.id
where a.created_by='06y'
and cast(created_at as date) = '2013-03-20'")
                    ?>
```

I'm confused on how to populate the data interacting upon mousedown and refresh sql data on the page as well. hope that makes sense. I haven't really tried much yet... still in the initial stages.

Comment: Do you have a URL scheme that includes the user name in the URL so your server knows which user to display?  If so, just hook up a javascript event listener for the `change` event on the select and then set the `window.location` to the URL with the new user in it.

Comment: i don't have the user in the $_Get but i could add them no problem.

Comment: Well you need something you can send to the server that says what user to display.  If it's a new page (and thus a new URL), then it should probably be part of your URL scheme so you can just construct the desired URL in your client-side javascript and set it to `window.location` and let the server process that URL and respond.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

In your `<select>` tag add  `onchange="window.location.href = this.value"`

Then you would populate the `<option>` tag with all appropriate users and their value would be their DB id, then you could use the `$_GET` method to query for that user.

I also added an `if` statement that has the user that is logged in show as selected in the drop-down

```
<?php
(isset($_GET['userid'])) ? $loggedUser = $_GET['userid'] : $loggedUser = '';
?>

<select name="username" onchange="window.location.href = this.value">
    <?php
    echo '<option value="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" selected></option>';
        // Array of usernames ($v) and their database id's ($k)
        foreach ($users as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == $loggedUser) {
                echo'<option value="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?userid='.$k.'" selected>'.$v.'</option>';
            } else {
                echo'<option value="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?userid='.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send the selected value in the onchange event of the selece
html:

```
<select id="users">
    <option value="1">1111</option>
    <option value="2">2222</option>
    <option value="3">3333</option>
    <option value="4">4444</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$('#users').on('change',function(){
   //get value of the select (suppose to be emp id)
   var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   //send it to some page on get url (can be post,ajax etc...)
   location.href = 'mypage.php?id=' + value; 
});
```